# How are specific objects accessed within a collection within a Django template?

Tags: python, django

The model:

```
class Panel(models.Model):
loc = models.IntegerField()
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

The template is supplied with Panel instances from the view:

```
def index(request):
return render_to_response('application/index.html', 
                          {"DEBUG": True,
                           "panels": Panel.objects.all() },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The template attempts to access a specific model instance as follows:

```
{% with panel = panels[1] %}
...presentation logic....
{% endwith %}
```

Currently this results in

TemplateSyntaxError at /applicatino/
u'with' expected at least one variable assignment

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063515/django-template-question-accessing-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the panel using `panels.1` in your template, like this:

```
{% with panel=panels.1 %}
   ...
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: This is correct if the spaces before and after the assignment are removed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up - I'm not super familiar with the `with` tag. I updated the answer.

Comment: Where did you find documentation on the .# reference ?

Comment: The spaces before and after the assignment should be removed.  I meet the same quesiton, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do:

```
list(Panel.objects.all())
```

in your controller, then in the template you can do:

```
{% for panel in panels %}
    <!-- your code here -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the for tag works with the model being instantiated as just Panel.objects.all()

I tried panels.get(loc=1) as well...

Comment: My question was regarding a method of retrieving a specific instance from a collection. 

for panel in panels works without the list() method