# Showing a random subset of emojis in my custom emoji keyboard (Django web app)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of 52 emojis, but I only want **10 to randomly show up** in an emoji cheat sheet/keyboard.

Here's what I'm doing:

A django view is passing my template a list of 10 random numbers between 1 and 52 like so: `context["random"] = random.sample(xrange(1,52),10)`

Separately, there's also a list of 52 emojis being passed, contained within the context variable `context["emojis"]`. This list looks like so:

`( [':)', ':-)', ':=)'], [':(', ':-(', ':=('], [';)', ';-)', ';=)', '(wink)'], [';(', ';-(', ';=(', '(cry)'], [':*', ':-*', ':=*', '(kiss)'], [':|', ':-|', ':=|', '(speechless)'], [':-?', ':?', ':=?', '(think)'], ['|(', '|-(', '|=(', '(dull)'], ['|-)', 'I-)', 'I=)', '(snooze)'], ['])', ']=)', '(grin)'], [':$', ':-$', ':=$', '(blush)'], [':D', ':-D', ':=D', ':d', ':-d', ':=d', '(laugh)'], [':O', ':-O', ':=O', ':o', ':-o', ':=o', '(surprised)'], ['8)', '8-)', '8=)', 'B)', 'B-)', 'B=)', '(cool)'], ['8-|', 'B-|', '8|', 'B|', '8=|', 'B=|', '(nerd)'])`

Those aren't all 52 emojis, but you get the idea. If I print `{{ emojis.5 }}` in my template, I'll see `[':*', ':-*', ':=*', '(kiss)']`. This result itself is a list because the kiss emoji can be made via all of those symbols.

So all in all, out of these 52 sub-lists, I want 10 `random` ones to appear in my template. Moreover, I only want to **print the first item** within each randomly selected sub-list.

Here's what I'm actually trying:

```
{% for index in random %}
{{ emojis.index.0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Nothing shows up. In my head, I thought this would get me the 10 random sub-lists via `emojis.index`, and the `.0` would ensure it only returns the first item.

Comment: Folks, ask me for more info in case I missed anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064242/3669062) is why that won't work.  TLDR: Dynamic indexing doesn't work in Django. You can do `{{ foo.5 }}`, but you can't do `{{ foo.{{bar}} }}`

What will work, however, is constructing your random list in your context before passing it (assuming `emojis` is a variable containing all your emoji):

`random_indexes = random.sample(xrange(1,52),10)
context["random_emojis"] = [emojis[ind] for ind in random_indexes]`

then in your template:

`{% for emoji in random_emojis %}
    {{ emoji.0 }}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: So doing it like that wouldn't be directly possible for me, since I'm using a plug-in (https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-emoticons) that pre-defines template tags for me. But I marked/upvoted it because under normal transmission, that's precisely how one would do it.